# c# Form.Hide() vs. Form.Opacity = 0

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, opacity

I was wondering if there are any gotchas for making a form completely transparent (as opposed to hiding it).  For instance, I know that these are things that got my by surprise when hiding a form:

1. If a form is hidden, you cannot interact with its controls (can't add HTML to a webbrowser control, can't push a button, etc.)
2. Changing the WindowState (minimized, maximized, etc) of a window while it is hidden will cause the window to appear outside the scope of your work area when the form is shown again.

Has anybody run into similar problems (or completely different ones!) while using a form with opacity set to 0 (completely transparent)?

Comment: Can't you still interact with the form with `Form.Opacity = 0`? So if it's completely transparent, I would think it'd be quite confusing...could potentially be trying to click on something behind your transparent window and not be able to actually interact with the other window...let alone accidentally triggering something in your transparent window.

Comment: @bitxwise:+1 ... this is exactly what happens to me.

Comment: Ahhh true!!  I hadn't thought about that.  I suppose you could change the opacity and move it outside the scope of the user's displays, and remove the taskbar icon as well.  Not sure it's worth the trouble.  Thanks for the input!!

Comment: Do all normal themes in Windows actually support Opacity (I am specifically thinking of Windows Home Server)? If it's not a target, then it can probably be ignored. I don't know the answer (though [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx) suggests support for Windows Server 2008 R2, which the latest WHS was written on top of, and WS 2003, which the older WHS was written on top of). I can try it later on my home server if no one knows the answer, and if you're interested.

Comment: @pickypg: Good point. Not all themes (or Windows versions for that matter) may support opacity.

I've moved my comment to an answer for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the up votes for my comment, I guess I'll submit it as an answer. I would discourage using `Form.Opacity = 0`. Even though you can disable the form to prevent accidental interaction, I would think the transparent form would overlay other windows and confuse the user as to why he can't interact with windows behind your transparent one.

As for the gotcha's for `Form.Hide()`, I typically queue form responses so that when the form returns into view (or visibility), it goes through the queue to process actions (i.e. changing FormState). Changing the form while it's hidden can also really confuse the user.

Comment: "I typically queue form responses"...  I need to learn how to do that - it sounds like the most useful thing ever.  Perhaps?  Perhaps!

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing out-of-the box for WinForms (like there is for WPF). So for WinForms, you will have to implement your own `Action` queue that is referenced when the form gains focus, which should cover your basic visibility needs since, as you know, the form cannot gain focus when it is hidden/invisible.

Comment: That's somewhat disappointing, but I suppose that's not new.  =)  Thanks again for all your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the form anymore, hide it.
But if you still have a task or timers running in the form you want to keep, or you want to keep the user's input, then you'd do good to set the opacity to 0%.
This is what I do when I want a form to be hidden, but still active:

```
frmMain.Opacity = 0; // To make it invisible.
frmMain.VisibleInTaskbar = false; // To make the taskbar entry of the form disappear, and to make sure that the WindowState isn't changed.
frmMain.Enabled = false; // To make sure the user doesn't type something in the form, or presses a button (by pressing enter) by accident.
```